# How can I create a circuit to poer up pc each 24 hours?

Tags: driver

I can't find idea or schematic for this in google, maybe certainly I search with the wrong terms, but I need plug on the pc to turn pc two times each 24 hours.

I found the circuit with 555 timer, but I can't found how use this 555 to  power up the rest of the circuit, in this case the pc!

I imagine will I need the battery, with the relay, maybe a some resistors, but I don't know how build this schematic/circuit to create this solution!

Thanks

Comment: There are neat programmable timer switches you can buy at nearby department store...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for being so off-topic, but I find it mildly interesting that a guy named Edgar accidentally makes the typo Poer (a different spelling of Poe).

Comment: @pipe Quoth the raven: Nevermore  OP: You could consider something like a Raspberry Pi with external relay board (care needs to be taken with mains wiring). The Pi could grab time from the network and keep on schedule, allow remote control etc.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please ask an actual question that is specific. Exactly what do you want to do? Review this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @laptop2d Ahem....

Comment: Do you mean power POE? Edit your question

Comment: @laptop2d I think the question is clear. How would power over ethernet make any sense? It's just bad Engrish.

Comment: Please edit your question with proper spelling and English. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to build a circuit and judging by your question you don't want to be building one for mains circuits. Most modern operating systems support wake up from sleep or hibernation on schedule. This should work for you if saving power is your primary goal.

- **Windows**: use Task Scheduler.
- **Mac OS**: System Preferences | Apple menu | System Preferences | Energy Saver icon in the System Preferences window ...
- **Linux**: rtcwake.

The Windows Task Scheduler help file says:

> **Power Conditions**
>
> You can set a condition that tells the task to run only if the computer is on AC power (not battery power) when the task trigger is activated. If this condition is set, you can also set a condition to stop the task if the computer switches to battery power. If both of these conditions are set for a task, then you have ensured that the task will only run when the computer is on AC power.
>
> You can also set a condition that tells the task to wake the computer from sleep mode to run the task when the trigger is activated. Before you set the condition to wake the computer to run the task, ensure that the task will not cause the computer to wake at inconvenient times.
>
> Note
> When the Task Scheduler service wakes, the computer to run a task, the screen may remain off even though the computer is no longer in the sleep or hibernate mode. The screen will turn on when Windows detects that a user has returned to use the computer.

See [HowtoGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/204742/how-to-make-any-computer-boot-up-or-shut-down-on-a-schedule/) for details.

Comment: Can it power up? Really? I feel old.. Update: Can't see such an option on my machine.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, it can't. Some people confuse powered off and sleep mode/power save states. Usually Apple-people, because their marketing has taught people that an Apple product boots instantly. This is of course not true, because it never turns off.

Comment: @pipe: I've edited to wake from sleep or hibernation. That makes sense for the OS triggered versions. I'm aware that some BIOS allow wake on RTC. Do you know if these will work from power-off? They _could_ as the RTC is battery powered.

Comment: @transistor Yes, the BIOS can wake up "for real" so to speak. The problem is, it can only do it once per day, at least in every single BIOS setting I've seen. I think this is why the OP is asking this question, because he wants it to boot twice.

Comment: @transistor but if I want which the pc repeat the behaviour? I read the manual, through man rtcwake, and I see how set the program to execute the operation at the certain time on the clock. But when the pc power up the process didn't repeat! I am thinking create the script for when pc power up ensure the behaviour it happens again.

Comment: What OS and flavour? Linux / ???

Comment: See [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/568114/pmset-multiple-repeating-schedule-pairs) - it may help. I recommend that you un-accept my answer for a day or so to see if better ones show up. The accept has the effect of making people not bother as the question seems to have been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: @transistor Ok, thanks to your advice. I founded this article on internet :) http://forums.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/2713-Guide-RTCwake-to-turn-off-on-your-nas-at-a-specific-time/ My system is Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I am reading this article, your link and the manual!